# Remove an event listener from a component only based off of its function name - Ext Js

Tags: javascript, extjs

Alright so I have a viewport divided into two halves, top and bottom.  The top half has combo boxes and input fields that are always visible, the bottom half has a tab panel with multiple tabs.

When I change one of the static combo boxes on the top half, I'll call it combo box `A`, it fires an event and in its event handler, `A_handler`,  it will attempt to style another combo box in one of the tabs, I'll call it combo box `B`, but it may do one of two things.

Combo box `B` is visible on tab `2`, not `1`.

So then:

1)  If tab `1` is active, it will setup an event handler to style combo box `B` for when tab `2` is made active.

2) Otherwise, it will just immediately style it.

So here's the problem:  The initial combo box, `A`, can style combo box `B` one of two possible ways, depending on the selection, say `red` and `blue`.

So imagine the situation where tab `1` is visible, and I select the option to style `B` as `red`, then the event handler is created for when tab `2` is activated.  But then, without activating tab `2`, I change the option again in combo `A`, to make box `B` as `blue`.

At this point, I need it to remove the first event handler so that only one is fired.

I do not have a reference to the event handlers, but I have named them.

I have created functions to acquire the list of event listeners on tab `2`, and know the name of the listener to remove, so I can match names, but the scopes are not the same when I attempt to remove them with the tab's `removeListener`, so nothing happens.

Comment: There's not much point describing how the code works. Post a test case.

Answer (score 1):

You may set event handlers to work only once:

```
someItem.on('event', function() {
    // ... bla bla bla ...
}, scope, {single:true});
```

Comment: thanks, but the problem isn't that the event handlers persist, in fact I already have them setup to fire only once. my issue is that I need a way to remove the event handler even before it fires once

Comment: So, use `un` method to remove event.

Comment: The `un` method is as follows: `un( eventName, fn, [scope] )`

A reference to the event handler function is required, which I don't have access to, hence the part of my title which says *"...based off of its function name"* Maybe I didn't explain that well enough in the post. I don't have access to a function ref for the handler because all of this code itself is in a more broad event handler itself, and nothing can be persistent - ie, no properties attached to a global object, or global vars

Comment: Thanks for the help though, but I found a solution.  It retrieves the function ref by a lookup from the function name

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

Eventually found the solution to this.

The `un` or `removeListener` functions are setup like this:

`un( eventName, fn, [scope] )`

My problem was that I did not have a reference to the specific handler to pass in for `fn`

The solution involves finding the `fn` ref by searching with the fn name.

So when the event listener is created, it is setup with a name:

`myTab.on('activate', function doSomeStuff() {`

Later on when I need to check if it exists/possibly remove it:

```
objectHasNamedListener: function(obj, eventType, name) {
  var listeners = obj.events[eventType].listeners;

  //trim functionality since .trim() doesn't exist in old IE
  name = name.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

  if (listeners != undefined) {
     for (var i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
        var func = listeners[i].fn;
        var funcStr = func.toString();
        var funcName = funcStr.substr('function'.length);
        funcName = funcName.substr(0, funcName.indexOf('('));
        funcName = funcName.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        if (funcName == name) {
           return true;
        }
     }
  }
  return false;
},
```

And if that returns true, get the reference to that handler:

```
if (this.objectHasNamedListener(myTab, "activate", "doSomeStuff")) {
    var listener = this.getNamedListener(myTab, "activate", "doSomeStuff");
    myTab.removeListener("activate", listener, this);
}




getNamedListener: function(obj, eventType, name) {
    var listeners = obj.events[eventType].listeners;

    name = name.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

    if (listeners != undefined) {
       for (var i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
          var func = listeners[i].fn;
          var funcStr = func.toString();
          var funcName = funcStr.substr('function'.length);
          funcName = funcName.substr(0, funcName.indexOf('('));
          funcName = funcName.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

          if (funcName == name) {
             return func;
          }
       }
    }

    return null;

 },
```

**The other caveat is that the listener had to be created and removed with the same scope passed in, despite the fact that it is listed as [optional] in the API, so passing in this worked fine**